# How to resolve slow scrolling issue in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionreusableview

Scrolling a collection view with a large number of supplementary header views is extremely slow. The more sections, the worst is the scrolling performance. (Tested with 5,000 sections).

Best to give it a try and see for yourself.

Code is available at https://github.com/yoasha/CollectionViewTest

To reproduce, run the demo app with Xcode on either iPhone or iPad simulator (or a real device), select "Collection View" on the main page, and try to scroll.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71604132/uicollectionview-how-to-fix-scrolling-issue) ... That sample code may not be the best approach for your needs. As a side note, having 5,000 sections in a collection view (or table view) is impractical -- no user is going to scroll that far. You probably want to rethink your UI/UX

Comment: 1) I accept your comment and apologize about the duplicate post. It's a second and last try getting help from the community as I hoped that a much shorter and more precise post will attract more attention. Sorry about that.

Comment: 2) Regarding the 5,000 sections I agree it sounds a lot, but this is only a test. I have real world cases with 2,000 sections which also present serious scrolling issues.

Comment: 3) Regarding UI/UX I must disagree, as the index titles feature completely targets  that. My users love to see their entire library (even though they have plenty of filters in the UI) and they use the title index frequently to jump from one area to another, so they don't actually need to scroll through all the sections.

Comment: 4) Lastly, even though it's not mentioned in my post, UITableView has no scrolling issue with 5,000 section. I actually tested with 10,000 sections, and scrolling is smooth. So technically speaking, why should collection and table views behave so differently in this aspect? Shouldn't I expect collection view to be as efficient and fast scrolling  as table view?

Comment: BTW, my demo includes a UITableView test that proves exactly what I just said, so you can give it a try.

Many thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: *"why should collection and table views behave so differently in this aspect?"* -- because they are two different classes, targeting different uses. As a *general rule* (yes, rules are made to be broken), for a "row" layout a table view is better suited. Collection views are more targeted toward flowing or compositional layouts. Without knowing anything else about your project, maybe that's something to be considered.

Comment: I imagine it's *possible* to modify that "sticky header/footer" collection view layout to avoid the delay with hundreds / thousands of items... but unless there is a specific reason to use a collection view instead of a table view, it might end up being a lot of work (well, a lot of time debugging / trying / failing / trying something else / failing / etc).

Comment: I completely agree with your perspective. Table views and collections views surely have different use cases. Thing is that my app currently provides only a list view (by using a table view). However, my users wish to have additional grid view which is perfectly suited for collection view. My approach was implementing both view types (list and grid) using a single collection view, thus remove a lot of headache of maintaining two different controls with lots of common code. Also, switching between controls sounds like a terrible workaround bringing lots of bugs.

Comment: As to sticky header/footer views, these custom views should inherit from UICollectionReusableView. However, even when I provide a new clean instance of UICollectionReusableView the issue is still there. So the issue is not related to any layout made by my own custom views. It seems like the internal invalidation code is not well optimized.